# panelChange binding a value on the panel Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jhipster

**Overview**

Im learning Angular and JHipster trying to get the id of an objet in a collection.

but I can't get the event click to work on the panel also a I can't use the panelChange event on the panel itself.

Is a DAFO analysis so i need the id to get the elements

**My thoughts**

think im donning wrong the binding or im using a different event

this is in the TypeScript side of the component

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ planEstrategico }) => {
            this.planEstrategico = planEstrategico;
            this.idPlan = planEstrategico.id; 
            this.cargarAnaliziFoda(this.idPlan);
        });

    }
      cargarElementosFoda(id) {
        console.log(id);
      }
```

first I try this

```
<ngb-panel
  (click)="cargarElementosFoda(diagnosticoFoda.id)"
  *ngFor="let diagnosticoFoda of diagnosticoFodas"
>
```

dint work so I try this

```
<ngb-panel
  (panelChange)="cargarElementosFoda(diagnosticoFoda.id)"
  *ngFor="let diagnosticoFoda of diagnosticoFodas"
>
```

also don't work

I read only works on the   `ngb-accordion`
but the problem is not all the panels are for DOFA just one or two.

**Questions**

- Best way to get the id of my collection with click event?
- Alternative ways to get the id? maybe on the typescript side of the
  component

**Notes**

- im really new on Angular, TypeScript and Jhipster please if I miss something important let me know it on the comment I will added to the question.

Comment: did you put the `cargarElementosFoda` function inside of the `ngOnInit` function or is that just weird code formatting?

Comment: @jahller Sorry, its outside a type error